# count people who have dual citzienship also

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m trying to count the number of people who are coming from different countries in sql server. But some people have dual citizen ship too. 
How to write query considering dual citizenship too and count people in both countries.

Example:

```
ID  CITIZENSHIP DUAL CITIZENSHIP
00000S123   US  ITALY
00000BH01   UK  
00000VA03   US  
00000SR01   UK  US
```

Ideally there are only two students with US citizen ship but it should be 3 as a student is also having dual citizenship for US.
Please note I don’t want to hard code in where clause

```
WHERE  DUAL_CITIZENSHIP='US'
```

Thanks,
S‌indhu

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: I think I understand you want the number of rows that have `CITIZENSHIP` of "US" and/or `DUAL CITIZENSHIP`of "US"? I don't understand the last sentence "don't want to hard code"... Which way do you want to code your query? What does your current query look like? If you post what you've tried so far and how it fails, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect, I believe you want the 1 row to become notionally 2 for the purposes of the count, with the dual citizen ship being pivoted down for a second row. You could of course query on citizenship = 'US' or dual_citizenship = 'US' but wish to avoid that double inclusion of the predicate.

Something like (table names were not provided):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, citizenship
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, dual_citizenship as citizenship
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE dual_citizenship is not null
) a
WHERE citizenship = 'US'
```

If you wanted all countries:

```
SELECT citizenship, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, citizenship
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, dual_citizenship as citizenship
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE dual_citizenship is not null
) a
GROUP BY citizenship
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union for merge the CITIZENSHIP

```
    select  ID,  CITIZENSHIP
    from my_table 
    where  CITIZENSHIP ='US'
    union  
    select  ID,  DUAL_CITIZENSHIP
    from my_table 
    where  CITIZENSHIP ='US'


select count(*) 
from (

    select  ID,  CITIZENSHIP
    from my_table 
    where  CITIZENSHIP ='US'
    union  
    select  ID,  DUAL_CITIZENSHIP
    from my_table 
    where  CITIZENSHIP ='US'

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT

```
Select T.Country, count(*)
from (
Select id,Country
from TABLENAME t
     unpivot (
     Country for c in (CITIZENSHIP ,DUALCITIZENSHIP)
     ) Unpvt
     ) T
WHERE len(Country)>0
Group by T.Country
```

If you want to filter by specific country, you can to where close

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte (Citizenship, NumberOfStudents) as (
    SELECT Citizenship, COUNT(*)
    FROM Students
    GROUP BY Citizenship
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DualCitizenship, COUNT(*)
    FROM Students WHERE DualCitizenship IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY DualCitizenship
)
SELECT Citizenship, SUM(NumberOfStudents) as NumberOfStudents
FROM cte
GROUP BY Citizenship;
```

The result is:

[image]